# I want to replace all last slashes from the url /abcd..... by using excel

Tags: excel, function, url, formula, excel-2016

I want to replace the last slash and any text attached to it by using excel formula and replace it with .jpg

Examples:
//example.com/123/abcd/image-adaptive-clothing/bluecolor
//example.com/123/abcd/image-blouse-image/greencolor

Note: There are 6 slashes in each URLs.

[image]

Advanced Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I believe that spaces are not valid characters in URLs so:

1. Use `Substitute` to replace the 6th `/` with a space i.e. `CHAR(32)`
2. Use `Mid` and `Search` to trim your string from the 1st character up until the space
3. Add on your `.jpg` string to the end

---

```
=MID(A2,1,SEARCH(CHAR(32),SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/",CHAR(32),6))-1) & ".jpg"
```

[image]

---

*I am choosing to use the space character since we can assume your string will not have any spaces present to start with. Therefore, when we search for it, we can assume the space that is found is the one we inserted*